# Flutter Container inside a Container and Text widget

Tags: flutter, containers

```
Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
        ),
```

when I do this why the child container size is the same as parent container size? but when i pass  `alignment: Alignment.center` inside the parent container, this give a expected output?

**Output**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Share your expected UI snippet and what you are currently getting

Comment: i added expected and unexpected UI

Answer (score 1):

Because the parent widget forces the child widget to be the same exact size.

From the docs:

> If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent
> doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size
> might be ignored. Be specific when defining alignment.

You could also wrap the inner Container in a Center widget and it would also work.

See the examples here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints